# How can I save a template email on my iPhone so I can send it repeatedly?

Tags: iphone, email

I am about to head to a Meetup, and I would like to be able to share my contact information with other people I meet. I wanted to save a "template" email on my iPhone containing my contact information with my vCard attached so I could open it up, enter a person's email address, send it to them, and then repeat for the next person I met.

If I save a draft email and send it, then the draft goes away and I can't send it again. Is there any way to resend an email from the iPhone to a new address, or any way to edit a sent message and send it again?

How can I save a template email on my iPhone so I can send it repeatedly?

Answer (score 7):

**Use the Note App!** Just type your email subject on the first line of the note. Hit return and type your body text. Each time you want to send this info to someone use the email function within the note. Your email is populated correctly and it's a really quick process. I use this system to send payment receipts to my guitar students.

Comment: As of January 2019 this still works very well (+1), but although the first line is correctly copied into the subject field it also remains in the body; is there a trick to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

You can write a **mailto** link in **Note** app like this:

> mailto:someone@example.com?subject=This%20is%20the%20subject&cc=someone_else@example.com&body=This%20is%20the%20body

Use `%20` to add a blank and `%3Cbr%3E` for a new line.

The **Note** app on iPhone will recognise this link. You can just tap it to create a new mail.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mailto

Answer (score 1):

You can send the template message to yourself and then forward it around to others. When forwarding you can select all text, scroll right in contextual menu to **quote level**, decrease qoute level and then delete forwarding info.

Comment: How do I decrease the quote level? That was the one reason I wasn't using the Forward feature?

Comment: @Josh - after you select something you have a right arrow in contextual menu which takes you to a new button **qoute level**

Comment: Okay, thanks... this works but it's very cumbersome. Also, "delete forwarding info" is easier said than done on an iPhone's touchscreen :-p

Comment: @Josh then perhaps it's easier to keep your intro text/ subject line in clipboard and your contact opened in Contacts so whenever you need to send your vcard you open Contacts, click share, email, paste said text, enter recipient and send.

Comment: That's an alternative. What I did for now was just created the draft on my Mac using Mail.app, right clicked and chose "Copy To...", chose the "Drafts" folder, selected both drafts, repeated the process, etc, until I had a whole bunch of drafts waiting to go. Mah. It will work for tonight.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few iPhone apps that can help you with email templates.

One such app is [Email & SMS Templates](http://www.emailandsmstemplates.com), an app that I have made. It will help you make a predefined email template with your contact information. It doesn't allow you to add attachments such as vCards in the current version though.

You can get the lite version which has all functionality except dropbox backup/restore of templates. And if you like it, support us by getting the full version and/or write a review.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the very same issue with both emails and text messages, as I wanted to be able to send email and SMS templates. So I created an app called `Actions - Fast forward everyday tasks` for the iOS platform.

The app allows you to **automate** all sorts of repetitive tasks including: **email templates**, text templates, viewing the news, weather reports, converting currencies and much more.

I believe my app could be of use to you, you can download it on the App Store: https://itunes.apple.com/app/id993488068

Answer (score 1):

I have used the ["Mail Aide"](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mail-aide/id1180678139?mt=8) app from the App Store, which allows for easily saving the draft and sending the same mail multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

If your email signature is not to long and if you have several email addresses, you can put your "template text" in the foot signature of your email.

I use it to post by email to Wordpress since there is no "offline app" that stores text and pictures accordingly

Answer (score 0):

In MailChimp 
Set up a list called meetups.
Fill in the relevant details, email etc. Turn on the welcome email in the list settings.
In list settings set up a form which you can access from a website.
In list settings, edit the welcome emails to include all the details you need, LinkedIn, website etc.

At the meet up use your phone and show the form to the person. They will fill in an email address and receive the welcome email.

You will receive their email.
And a list to follow up after.

This is great for boot he's set up on a laptop.. Where the welcome email contains special Info. For example contains a link to a special website. Or is the only way to enter a prise draw.

If you are brave enough you could live it by itself on a laptop chained to a table and see what happens. Sign optional.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I require a way that doesn't use MailChimp

Answer (score -1):

Try out Crisp, the email template keyboard, just released for iOS. It allows you to save unlimited templates and has iCloud sync across your devices. The best part - you can quickly send the template from any app (email, messages, social media) just by using the custom keyboard. You can download the Crisp - Email Template Keyboard at
https://appsto.re/us/ax-I8.i

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Feel free to self-disclose if you made the app. That usually prevents removal for spam - especially if you participate here for more than marketing reasons.